# How to get top 5 in list from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following is DataSet that I have used!

```
df_kaggle = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smeet-kothari/SM-Portfolio-Manager/master/EQUITY_L.csv')
df_kaggle.head()
```

I want to get the top 5 companies occurring in data frame

```
top5 = df_kaggle['NAME OF COMPANY'].value_counts().head(5)
companies = df_kaggle['NAME OF COMPANY'].isin(top5)
companies.value_counts()
```

My Output :
False    1637
Name: NAME OF COMPANY, dtype: int64

Instead of this method if I use tolist()
the list is [2,2,2,1,1] but I want the name of companies instead of how many times they are occurring.

Thanks for the Solution in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chain `nlargest()` method with `value_counts()` method:

```
top5=df_kaggle['NAME OF COMPANY'].value_counts().nlargest(5)
```

If you want company names then:

```
company_names=top5.index
```

And If you want data of top5 company then make use of boolean mask and `isin()` method:

```
mask=df_kaggle['NAME OF COMPANY'].isin(top5.index)
result=df_kaggle[mask]
```

Comment: I forgeted top5.index that's why all mask were false thanks man!